# Is definable power sufficient to interpret ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

This post is actually related to posting titled *[What is the strength of definable ZFC?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124774/what-is-the-strength-of-definable-zfc)*. However the presentation there was '*semiformal*', and here I'll present a complete formal exposition of that theory.

To the language of ZFC minus Power, lets add a primitive one place predicate symbol $``definable"$, and lets add the following *Omega inference rule:*

if $\{\phi_1(y),\phi_2(y),\phi_3(y),...\}$ is the set of ALL formulae in the language of ZFC, in just one free variable symbol $``y"$; and if $\psi(X,w_1,..,w_m)$ is a formula in the language of ZFC, in which all and only symbols $``X,w_1,..,w_m"$ occur free, then:

\begin{equation}
  \text{ for each m=0,1,2,...; $w_1,..,w_m$  }  
\begin{cases}
 \forall X\ [\forall y (y \in X \leftrightarrow \phi_1(y))\to \psi(X,w_1,..,w_m)]\\
 \forall X\ [\forall y (y \in X \leftrightarrow \phi_2(y))\to \psi(X,w_1,..,w_m)]\\
 \forall X\ [\forall y (y \in X \leftrightarrow \phi_3(y))\to \psi(X,w_1,..,w_m)]\\
\ . \\
\ . \\
\ . \\
\rule{10,cm}{1,pt} \\
\forall X [definable(X) \to \psi(X,w_1,..,w_m)] \\
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

This is a schema of inference rules whose antecedent is also schema! It means for each particular substitution of $m$ and $w_1,..,w_m$: if *ALL* sentences  $``\forall X\ [\forall y (y \in X \leftrightarrow \phi_n(y))\to \psi(X,w_1,..,w_m)]"$, where $n=1,2,3,...$; were fulfilled! Then we infer the sentence below the line.

This would ensure that every set $x$ that fulfills the predicate "$definable$" is a set definable after a parameter free formula in the language of ZFC.

Proof: suppose there exists a set $s$ that is not parameter free definable, then take $m=1$ and substitute $w_1$ by $s$, and run the omega rule above for the formula $\psi(X,w_1)$ being the formula $X \neq s$, the antecedent schema would be fulfilled, and so by that omega rule, we infer that every definable set $X$ must satisfy $X \neq s$

Add the ***axiom scheme of definability***: if $\phi(y)$ is a formula in the langauge of ZFC, in which only the symbol $``y"$ occurs free, then: $$\forall X\ [\forall y (y \in X \leftrightarrow \phi(y))\to definable(X)]$$; is an axiom

From the above omega rule and the definability axiom scheme, the equivalence of the predicate $definable$ with definability after a parameter free formula in the language of ZFC is established!

Now to ZFC minus power, lets add the "***definable power set axiom***" that is:

$\forall A \exists x \forall y \ [y \in x \leftrightarrow y \subseteq A \wedge definable(y)]$

Question: Would that theory still interpret ZFC over the hereditarily definable realm of this theory?

Comment: I imagine Choice would typically fail quite badly.

Comment: @EricWofsey, can you elaborate on this point please.

Comment: Well, why would Choice be true?  I don't know how to construct a counterexample but there is no reason to expect a definable set to have a definable choice function (or more weakly, something definable that behaves like a choice function when restricted to just the definable sets).

Comment: @EricWofsey, but why wouldn't the same argument of your's apply to Godel's constructible universe?

Comment: @Zuhair Gödel obtained a global well ordering, because his notion of definability is defined with recourse to the ordinals in his Definable hierarchy.